# having server generated data available to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JavaScript which needs access to some data available on the server.  In the past, I just used PHP to include some JavaScript in the original page download which would create an object, and used that.  I would like to try doing so differently, and instead download some JSON and use that.

How is this accomplished.  I made up the following and don't know if it is the "right" way.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            //Disable all events using JavaScript.  How is this done?
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Allow events which were previously disabled 
            //$(function(){}); not needed since end of the page
            $.getJSON( 'getMyJSONstuff.php', function(myJSONstuff) {
                $('#elem1').plugin1({x:myJSONstuff.x});
                $('#elem2').plugin2({y:myJSONstuff.y});
            });
            $('#elem3').plugin2({y:123});
            $('#elem4').plugin3({z:321});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is requirement "//Disable all events using JavaScript.  How is this done?" ?

Comment: Why "Disable all events using JavaScript. How is this done?" isn't a new question? Laziness?

Comment: @ErickPetrucelli  Your right.  I'll remove it.